# Script to show history of recent changes

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Please help in ending of some script on Google Sheets. Now it goes like:

```html
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  
  // Note: actRng = return the last cell of the row modified
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var cindex = actRng.getColumnIndex();
  
  // Note: date = return date + time
  // Note: user = return the user email
  var dateCol = sheet.getLastColumn();  
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange(index,dateCol);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+0300", "dd-MM-yy HH:mm");
  
  //var user = event.user;  // Note: event.user will not give you collaborator's Id
  var user = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  
  // Note: setcomment = Inset a comment with the user email
  // Note: setValue = Insert in the cell the date + time when this row was modified
  lastCell.setValue("'" + date + " " + user).setComment(user);
}
```

[end acts like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHPKG.jpg)
[image]

So when you put a mouse on a cell with a date and time it shows an email address of person who did last changes, at least the last ten.

Any help or advice on how to change this code?

Comment: Is there something in particular that doesn't work? I'm not sure what exactly the problem is here.